# IIS7: Separate IP Addresses Vs Same IP Address with Separate Ports

Tags: iis-7, port, ip-address

I am setting up multiple sites on IIS7.

What are the pros and cons of:
**Setting up all the sites on the same IP address but different ports**
versus
**Setting up all the sites on different IP addresses.**

Also,what are the implications for SSL certificates(any any other aspects that you may know of) between the above two approaches?

Comment: Btw, this really belongs on serverfault.com. Have voted to migrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, each site that uses SSL, must be bound to an IP address. SSL sites can only be segmented by IP (and port) and cannot be segmented by host name.

The only implication by segmenting by host is that if a given site goes down (literally stopped) and if there is a site listening only on IP, it will "choose" that site. So, the effect is a user goes to site A and sees the stuff from site B. If all sites segment on host, this isn't a problem.

For public sites that assume 80 and 443 for http and https, you really can only segment on IP or host. Most users will not be expecting to navigate to something on a different port and you would need to open special ports on the hosting system's firewall to allow for requests on those ports.